# Generic ASM1064 4-Port SATA Controller works under Manjaro but not under Ubuntu, why?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, kernel, ubuntu-mate, 21.10

I've just installed a generic SATA PCIe x1 4-port controller in my Ubuntu 21.10 Mate, (with kernel 5.13) box and found it didn't work. (Well the drives were detected but `gparted` hangs and errors). It uses the ASMedia 1064 chip. Motherboard is MSI b460m pro-vdh wifi.
I've upgraded to the `5.15.2-051502-generic` kernel with no change.

`lspci -v` shows, as far as I know, the correct information:-

```
04:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1064 (rev 02) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ZyDAS Technology Corp. Device 2116
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 149
    Memory at 92182000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at 92180000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Expansion ROM at 92100000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [80] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [130] Secondary PCI Express
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
```

However, if I boot `manjaro-mate-21.1.2-210907-linux513.iso` on same hardware (using a USB Stick), Manjaro works fine. I was able to rsync about 70Gs off the drives with no errors.

lspci -v looks pretty similar, and so does the ata/ahci driver files - although they are shown as .ko files on Ubuntu and .xz on Manjaro.

`modinfo ahci` on both machines show a version 3 driver.

Can anyone suggest what to do to get this controller working on Ubuntu.